# Unexpected Outputs in Left Shift Operation...?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I read that Left shift `e1<<e2` is equivalent to `e1* 2e2`.
But for the code:

```
x=5;
printf("%d",x<<3);
```

Output is **40** but according to me it should be **30**.
and for `x<<4` it is **80** .(but expected **40**).

Although for `x<<1` and `x<<2` outputs are **10** and **20** as expected.

Please explain this logic.

Comment: Dont knw y the whole ques didnt display.My full ques was:
I read that Left Shift e1<<e2 is equiavalent to e1* 2e2 .But for the code:

Comment: You urgently need a new keyboard. Some of your current keyboard's keys seem to be stuck, rendering your text almost unintelligibly. And if you, at least once per year, wipe the dust your monitor, you can actually _see_ those typos as they happen.

Comment: -1 for bad formatting and telling us what (wrong) output you expect with no indication why you think that should be the output.

Comment: Plz dont be so rude.. it'll nt happen again and plz tk back the -1.

Comment: And ya I included the comment later that I read that e1<<e2 is equivalent to e1*2*e2 thats y I was expecting that Output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

00000101 = 4 + 1 = 5

00101000 = 32 + 8 = 40

Left shift is not successive multiplication by 2, 4, 6, 8 (i.e. x*2)—it's successive multiplication by 2, 4, 8, 16 (i.e. x^2).

Answer (score 1):

No, 40 is quite right...

What you seem to be expecting is this: "x * 2 * n", but left shift is a different operation.

You can think of left shift as an efficient "x * 2^n" where n is the number - in your case 3. So what you're doing is 5 * 8, which *is* 40.

Same goes for 80: 5 * 16, which is 80.

Comment: Thank you.I thought Left Shift e1<<e2 is equal to e1*2*e2..Thats y I was not getting my result.

Comment: @Brite: If you think an answer was helpful, you are encouraged to accept it. You might want to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).